# Is passing literal string as template parameter not good

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, string-literals

I'm working on a c++ project and I just defined a function as below:

```
template<typename... Args>
void func(Args&&... args) {}
```

Then, call it like this:

```
func("abc"); // char[4]?
func("de");  // char[3]?
```

My question is if the compiler will deduce two independent functions, one is for `char[4]` and the other is for `char[3]`? If I call many `func` with `const char*` as above, the compiler will generate many independent functions?

Is this stupid? Should I avoid this?

In fact, `func("abc")` and `func(std::string("abc"));` are exactly the same for me.

So should I call this function like `func(std::string("abc"));` and `func(std::string("de"));` so that the compiler will generate only one function as `void func(const std::string&);`

BTW, My project is developed with C++14.

Comment: It may be useful to try your code at https://godbolt.org/ to see what various compilers will produce with various build flags.

Comment: Yes, a function will be generated for each size of string literal.  If you use a `std::string`, you run the risk of dynamic allocation, so it's a compile time/executable space vs run time cost tradeoff.  If most of your strings are short, like less than 15 characters, then you would benefit from SSO and it makes the tradeoff even more nuanced.  Personally unless you notice it becoming an issue I would stick with what you currently have.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on what you expect this function to do. Does it always work with strings? Does it work with array-like objects? Etc. When using templates I personally always follow the mantra of defining the most constrained template possible, that way it is more predictable what the compiler generates. Variadic templates are usually only used as a last resort (or as a "forwarder") as it is really fiddly to unspool the template parameter pack down the line if needed.

Comment: This depends a lot. If the function is short, it will probably get inlined anyway, so you would be losing nothing. Otherwise, you have to ask yourself, in real code, how many hard-coded strings are you going to be using? Also it may be worthwhile considering a more STL style interface using beginning and ending character pointers or using `std::string_view` (and maybe `std::span`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if the compiler will deduce two independent functions, one is for char[4] and the other is for char[3]?

It will.

> If I call many func with const char* as above, the compiler will generate many independent functions?

You don't call `func`  with `const char*`. If you did call `func` with only `const char*` then there would be only one instantiation of the function template.

You call the function with `const char[4]` and `const char[3]` which do cause separate instantiations. There will be an instantiation for each unique sets of template arguments.

> Is this stupid? Should I avoid this?

Depends on use case. In many cases, the optimiser simply expands all calls inline and the instantiations won't leave any trace of their theoretical existance in the generated assembly.